# Stop Django background-task from deleting completed_task model

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, background-task

On `django-background-tasks==1.1.11` (`Django==2.2`, `Python 3.6.9`), I have this problem where everytime I run `python manage.py migrate`, the table `background_task_completedtask` gets deleted. This breaks my background tasks. So far I have found a way to reverse it, as it is a separate migration from the initial one, meaning I can just `python manage.py migrate background_task 0001_initial` to restore it, but this does mean it will still be removed next migration.
Any ideas for a more permanent solution?

Comment: If you go through each of your migration files, do any of them look like they will delete that table?

Comment: The comments for my own apps: no. There is a `background_task` migration called `0002_delete_completedtask` but I don't know where that is stored and think that if I delete it it will simply reappear on the next `makemigrations`

Comment: Is it in an external package then? Could you `cd` to your virtual environment's directory and run `find . -name "*0002_delete_completedtask*"`? 

You might have previously uninstalled the `django-background-tasks` app and then ran `makemigrations` which would've generated the migration. Try and delete it, make sure the app is installed and then run `makemigrations` again to check that it doesn't get generated again.

Comment: Yes, it is an external package, `django-background-tasks==1.1.11` to be precise. Deleted the migration (and cache), ran makemigrations and it simply recreated the migration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a (somewhat hacky) permanent solution myself:
By faking migrations (`python manage.py migrate --fake` (or `python manage.py migrate appname --fake`)), you make django think the migration has been executed without actually executing it. By doing this with the migration that was bothering me, I managed to get everything working again.